# Change TextView padding dynamic on widget

Tags: android, dynamic, widget, textview, padding

I tried to change the padding of a TextView which is placed on a widget.
Direct via 'findViewById' it isn't possible because the class extends from AppWidgetProvider.

Therefore I tried to use remoteViews.setBundle with the following
code. But this is not a solution.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle(4);
b.putInt("left", 5);b.putInt("top", 5);b.putInt("right",
5);b.putInt("bottom", 5);
remoteViews.setBundle(R.id.name1, "setPadding", b);
```

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Tagging it as android should help find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. If you look at the android source the setPadding method is not marked with "@RemotableViewMethod" which allows it's value to be set by the RemoteViews object. The only hack we found was to use a different layout.